# how to improvise filechooser,without showing file types drop down?

Tags: java

Here i used filechooser to select the folder and selected the all the files which was named with MANI.TXT and try to remove c: reference from the file, i need help to improvise filechooser code,without showing file of types drop down?

```
                    JFileChooser    chooser = new JFileChooser(); 
            //chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Choose workSpace Path");

    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
    System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): " + chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
    System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
    }


 String path= chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
    File folder = new File(path);
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement a custom [`FileSystemView`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html).